# What does this code imply: ss:dword_410CC5[ebp]?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, ida

Using IDA Pro for analysing a file, I have run across some code that I don't quite understand:

```
mov eax, ss:dword_410CC5[ebp] ;
call eax; Indirect Call Near Proc
```

Going to this address - 410CC5 - I see this:

```
 ile.........Clos
 eHandle.........
```

I assumed that in the first code snippet in EAX the name of library function is stored, which is then called by

```
call eax; Indirect Call Near Proc
```

But the problem is the address 410CC5 does not fully correspond to this name (see attachment). At this address are actually just zeroes.

Does that anyway means that at

```
call eax; Indirect Call Near Proc
```

we call CloseHandle? If so, then why isn't the right address passed to EAX?

[image: Code snippet]

Comment: `dword_410CC5[ebp]` is not absolute address `410CC5`, the value of `ebp` should be added. It's just a silly syntax for `[ebp+410CC5]`. Also, `call eax` will not invoke a function by name.

Comment: Surely, in that first line of code, there is a `MOV` instruction missing?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Corrected

Comment: You are looking at the IAT (Import Address Table) of a module.  While EBP normally addresses the stack frame, it does get used as a general purpose register in heavily optimized code.  Some odds that it simply calls an imported function.  Also tells you that you'll have a hard time getting somewhere, optimized code is quite hard to reverse-engineer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `call` instruction appears in the disassembly, it means that another routine/function is called at that point.

If the routine has an absolute address, the instruction will appear like `call 0xaabbccdd`.

If the address of the function being called is a dynamic address (this kind of addresses are resolved when the OS loads the executable), it's called via an enregistered value.

However, this instruction is used for calling a routine—that's all.